# Investigating malicious DMG file on MacOSX

Tags: security

I've got a Android Studio on my MAC. While I was installing it, I went to check the `SHA256` of it. So I realized this was not an original package. I would like to understand what is it, why, and explore what are my choices.

First of all, I know I should not have started the installation before checking the signature. I know, my bad. So, trying to fix the situation and understand with might have happened.

I have a few things I would like to understand:

1. If the signature does not match, it is a 100% sure this is a malicious package?
2. If yes, what tool can I use to explore what this package has inside, and what it did to my machine?
3. What kind of tool I can run to check if any OS command has been overwritten? I mean, I am not sure even if a simple copy operation might do something else.
4. I wanted to get the real dmg and compare to the weird one, is there a way of comparing two dmg files? Some kind of diff command?

I am not a security expert, but I am learning better practices of how to make things more securely. I am pretty sure I receive a lot of malicious emails, files, and connections attempts. Just trying to learn how to protect myself a little bit more.

I would like to avoid having to reset the machine, but it seems the best way to go. But I need my backups... So

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

The name of the files are the same, same version: android-studio-ide-173.4819257-mac.dmg

I ran: shasum -a 256 android-studio-ide-173.4819257-mac.dmg

And I got this:
d4a8502c5aabfc5477ff30dfffe296bf705bd7e62650a76796b646a8f28b5e5c

And I am supposed to get this (from developer.android.com):
21ec7cf480bfa05ff90594e9cebd0f79892e41d37b4a14988dce04a6fbb76b58

I don’t know the relevance of this, but I’ve got a syspolicyd message from MacOSX saying:

assessment denied for android-studio-ide-173.4819257-mac.dmg
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.security.assessment.outcome2
com.apple.message.signature2: bundle:UNBUNDLED
com.apple.message.signature4: 3
com.apple.message.signature3: android-studio-ide-173.4819257-mac.dmg
com.apple.message.signature5: UNKNOWN
com.apple.message.signature: denied:no usable signature
SenderMachUUID: F8DBBA1F-DCAE-3434-9083-DC560D8032D5

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you computed the SHA256 hash of, and what you compared it to? I assume you're aware that every different version and package will have a completely different SHA256 hash, so the fact that your hash doesn't match some other version doesn't mean anything? Or were you checking a signature (which is quite different from a hash)?

Comment: Gordon, I updated the question. Yes it is just an integrity check with sha checksum 256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the disk image is correct, and all that's wrong is that the website has the wrong SHA256 listed for some reason.

I just downloaded the disk image from https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads, and I get the same SHA256 checksum you do. The application file in the disk image has a valid signature from Google (see below), and I don't see anything else in the disk image that could be suspicious. Note that the disk image itself is not signed, but this is not a problem.

```
$ codesign -dvvv --deep /Volumes/Android\ Studio\ 3.1.3/Android\ Studio.app
Executable=/Volumes/Android Studio 3.1.3/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier=com.google.android.studio
Format=app bundle with Mach-O universal (i386 x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=537 flags=0x0(none) hashes=11+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=bac9739e22e0c9da7499d33bafc4b211b1950cc4
CandidateCDHash sha256=6507a87b8b1e550e5467d2a8ecd82c9dc02a27f4
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CDHash=6507a87b8b1e550e5467d2a8ecd82c9dc02a27f4
Signature size=8949
Authority=Developer ID Application: Google, Inc. (EQHXZ8M8AV)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=Jun 4, 2018, 2:33:20 PM
Info.plist entries=20
TeamIdentifier=EQHXZ8M8AV
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=13287
Internal requirements count=1 size=188

$ codesign -vvvv --deep /Volumes/Android\ Studio\ 3.1.3/Android\ Studio.app
/Volumes/Android Studio 3.1.3/Android Studio.app: valid on disk
/Volumes/Android Studio 3.1.3/Android Studio.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

$ spctl -avvv /Volumes/Android\ Studio\ 3.1.3/Android\ Studio.app
/Volumes/Android Studio 3.1.3/Android Studio.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: Google, Inc. (EQHXZ8M8AV)

$ codesign -dvvv ~/Downloads/android-studio-ide-173.4819257-mac.dmg
/Users/gordon/Downloads/android-studio-ide-173.4819257-mac.dmg: code object is not signed at all
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Gordon! I already have opened a documentation bug report on Google Developers Group. With this information I think I am good to go!

Comment: Do you know what is the policy message on my Mac? It seems there is something wrong after all.

Comment: I haven't compared with my Mac, but I'm pretty sure that's just the disk image mount process noticing that the image isn't signed. Image signing is only required under certain circumstances (that AFAIK don't apply here), so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> If the signature does not match, it is a 100% sure this is a malicious package?

No. You only know that the package has a checksum is different from the one the developer shipped. The cause of that also be that the download is corrupt (check and see what happens when you download the original a second time, is that different from the first download ?)

Comment: I downloaded again and it is the same file. I erased completely the first installation.  Before I install it again I need to check what is going on! Thanks.